# Create method to iterate through array and format phone number in C

Tags: c, arrays, printing, printf

I am new to programming in C, and I'm working on a simple program to take the user input (a basic phone number, ie: (678)-653.7539), and will output it in standard format).

The approach I took was first taking out all periods, hyphens, and parenthesis.

Currently the program prints out just numbers, however the format I want is:

(xxx) xxx-xxxx

I'm thinking creating a method with an array, and then iterating through (similar to stack?) having it input "(" before i[0] and again after i[2], and so on.

Is this the right approach?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeHyphen( char s[], char x );
void removeLeftParen( char s[], char f );
void removeRightParen( char s[], char g );
void removePeriod( char s[], char h );

int main()
{
    char s[50];

    printf("Enter your phone number:\n");
    scanf("%s", s);

    printf( "Your phone number: %.13s\n", s );

    removeHyphen( s, '-' );
    removeLeftParen(s, '(');
    removeRightParen(s, ')');
    removePeriod(s, '.');

    printf( "Formatted phone number: %.10s\n", s );


    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void removeHyphen(char s[], char x)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; s[i] != 0 ; ++i)
    {
        while(s[i]==x)
        {
            j=i;
            while(s[j]!=0)
            {
                s[j]=s[j+1];
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
}

void removeLeftParen(char s[], char f)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; s[i] != 0 ; ++i)
    {
        while(s[i]==f)
        {
            j=i;
            while(s[j]!=0)
            {
                s[j]=s[j+1];
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
}

void removeRightParen(char s[], char g)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; s[i] != 0 ; ++i)
    {
        while(s[i]==g)
        {
            j=i;
            while(s[j]!=0)
            {
                s[j]=s[j+1];
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
}

void removePeriod(char s[], char h)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; s[i] != 0 ; ++i)
    {
        while(s[i]==h)
        {
            j=i;
            while(s[j]!=0)
            {
                s[j]=s[j+1];
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, I have seen people repeating theme selves but you beat them all, `remove*` functions are all the same, you changed their name, but still pass the character to remove, having just one `removeChar()` would be a lot better.

Comment: Generally known as "parsing", [Google has some code](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

Comment: Homework?  In any case, the pseudocode I would choose would be to create a string to hold your output, and simply loop through the input once, adding the appropriate output characters by counting as you go along, and only adding numbers to your output as you encounter them in your input.  If your final output string is longer or shorter than the length of your expected output, it's an invalid input.

Comment: I'm a database admin, but I'm trying to learn C and bash. I found this online as an assignment for a cs class (mit, I think), but no solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need all the remove logic. You may just iterate over the input and copy the numeric characters.

Pseudo-code idea:

```
char output[50];   // better: char output[sizeof input];
                   // This is essentially processed/normalized input.
                   // In fact, since we know that it is a 10-digit
                   // phone number we can just do: char output[10];
                   // If you ever need to store the phone number for
                   // long term, the last option may be the best option.

const int n = actual length of input, e.g. strlen()
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (isdigit((unsigned char) input[i]) {
    output[j++] = input[i];
  }
}

// Validate 'output', for e.g. check that it has 10 characters

// Print output in desired format
```

See manual page for [`isdigit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html).

A different program structure employing the same idea is the following. While accepting input, scan them as characters and ignore the non-digit characters.

Comment: Dear Down Voter: Would you please comment so that I can learn and the answer may be improved?

Comment: NMDV, but `(int)` serve little purpose.  Suspect you want `isdigit((unsigned char) input[i])` to prevent UB.

Comment: @chux: Per the man page, the parameter to `isdigit()` is `int`. There should not be any problem in promoting `char` to `int`.

Comment: There is not problem promoting a `char` to an `int`, but the compiler will do that anyway - so the cast `(int)` is superfluous.  The point is that `isspace()` is not defined for all `char` should `char ` be signed.  `isspace()` is defined for all `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  So if `input[i]` has a value like `-2`, `isspace(-2)` is UB.  The typical solution is to cast the `char` to `unsigned char` first and then let the compiler further expand that to `int`.

Comment: Rather than the man page, from the C spec "In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."  §7.4 1  From the man page "These functions check whether c, which must have the value of an unsigned char or EOF ..."

Comment: @chux: Thanks a lot! That is a very good point. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You know exactly what your end product should look like. It'll be `char result[15]`. So a simple brute force algorithm would look like:

```
//set the known characters in the output string
result[ 0 ] = '(';
result[ 4 ] = ')';
result[ 5 ] = ' ';
result[ 9 ] = '-';
result[ 14 ] = '/0'; //null terminator

int index = 0;

//pseudocode
foreach( character in input )
    if character is a number 
        if index == 0, 4, 5, 9
            ++index;
        if index == 14 //we're out of room
            print result;
            exit;
        result[ index++ ] = character;
    else 
        ignore character
```

Where "character is a number" would probably be the only function you'd need to write.

Answer (score 0):

After you have removed all the unwanted characters you can do this

```
void printFormatted(char *s)
{
    int i;
    if (s == NULL)
        return;
    fputc('(', stdout);
    for (i = 0 ; ((i < 3) && (s[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
        fputc(s[i], stdout);
    fputc(')', stdout);
    fputc(' ', stdout);
    if (s[i] == '\0')
        return;
    for ( ; ((i < 6) && (s[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
        fputc(s[i], stdout);
    fputc('-', stdout);
    if (s[i] == '\0')
        return;
    for ( ; s[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
        fputc(s[i], stdout);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Although you don't really need to remove anything if you are just interested in the output of the program, you could use this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void printFormatted(char *phone);

int main()
{
    char phone[50];

    printf("Enter your phone number: ");
    if (scanf("%49s%*c", phone) == 1)
    {
        printf( "Your input            : %s\n", phone);
        printf("Formatted phone number : ");
        printFormatted(phone);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int putdigit(char digit)
{
    /* Print a charater if it's a digit (0-9) */
    if (isdigit((int)digit) == 0)
        return 0;
    fputc(digit, stdout);
    return 1;
}

void printFormatted(char *phone)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    /* Always be safe */
    if (phone == NULL)
        return;
    /* Output the `(' */
    fputc('(', stdout);
    /* Output 3 digits */
    for (i = 0, j = 0 ; ((j < 3) && (phone[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
        j += putdigit(phone[i]);
    /* Output the `)' and a space */
    fputc(')', stdout);
    fputc(' ', stdout);
    /* Check if there are more characters */
    if (phone[i] == '\0')
        return;
    /* Output 3 digits */
    for (j = 0 ; ((j < 3) && (phone[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
        j += putdigit(phone[i]);
    /* Output the hypen */
    fputc('-', stdout);
    /* Check if there are more characters */
    if (phone[i] == '\0')
        return;
    /* Output the rest of the characters */
    for ( ; phone[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
        putdigit(phone[i]);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of `strtok`.
The following is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char s[50], f[50];
    char *part[3] = { NULL };
    char *p;
    int i;

    printf("Enter your phone number:\n");
    scanf("%49s", s);

    printf( "Your phone number: %s\n", s );

    p = strtok(s, "-().");
    for(i=0; p!=NULL && i<3; ++i){
        part[i] = p;//Better to add one of the check is made up of numbers.
        p = strtok(NULL, "-().");
    }
    if(i==3){
        sprintf(f, "(%s) %s-%s", part[0], part[1], part[2]);
        printf( "Formatted phone number: %s\n", f );
    } else {
        printf("invalid format\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are other situations in which you are supposed to use strtok? Is that generally better to use?

Comment: @Megan It is easier than individually remove the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.  Build the string per an interpreted format.

```
#include <ctype.h>

// 0: success, 1 fail
int FormatPhoneNumber(const char *format, char *dest, const char *src) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; format[i]; i++) {
    if (format[i] == 'x') {
      while (!isdigit((unsigned char) *src)) {
        if (*src++ == '\0') {
          dest[i] = '\0';
          return 1;  // fail, missing digit
        }
      }
      dest[i] = *src++;
    } else {
      dest[i] = format[i];
    }
  }
  dest[i] = '\0';
  while (*src && !isdigit((unsigned char) *src)) src++;
  return *src ? 1 : 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  const char format[] = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx";
  char buf[sizeof format];
  int result = FormatPhoneNumber(format, buf, " (678)-653.7539),");
  printf("%d '%s'\n", result, buf);
  result = FormatPhoneNumber(format, buf, "Jenny: 111-867-5309");
  printf("%d '%s'\n", result, buf);
  return 0;
}
```

> 0 '(678) 653-7539'
>   0 '(111) 867-5309'